# Configure django UserManager to input date of birth for superuser?

Tags: python, django, django-users

Been messing with django 1.5 by creating my custom user model.  In my model, I have a required field dob = DateTimeField().  I've kept pretty much the UserManager and the AbstractUser the same.  However, when I try to python manage.py createsuperuser, I don't input the dob and I get the error:

IntegrityError: null value in column "dob" violates not-null constraint

How do I edit UserManager to allow me to input the date of birth in the terminal and I do I configure the input to store as DateTimeField in the db?

Edit my answer:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, dob=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email must be given')
        email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                          is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                          last_login=now, date_joined=now, dob=dob, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, dob, **extra_fields):
        u = self.create_user(username, email, password, dob, **extra_fields)
        u.is_staff = True
        u.is_active = True
        u.is_superuser = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u


# ... in the user model:
...
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'dob']
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite `REQUIRED_FIELDS` in the model that inherits from `AbstractUser`. Browsing through `contrib/auth/models.py` one can notice how `AbstractBaseUser` has `REQUIRED_FIELDS = []` and `AbstractUser` has `REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']`. My guess would be you should have something like:

```
class MyCoolUserModel(AbstractUser):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'dob']
    ...
```

**EDIT**: Not a guess any more. It works.

Generally speaking you can look what `createsuperuser` does by having a look at `contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py`. Any non-auth command can be located at `core/management/commands/`. Pretty much any `manage.py` issue can be resolved by having a look at the source of the command.